# How do I disable vertical scroll on a website on desktop and laptop screen resolutions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

so we are designing a website for a client, we are building our design to a wordpress frame work, the problem is we need the website to be totally unscrollabe on the screen for desktops and laptops.

The div content (main content) where the content overflows has vertical scroll but in general the whole screen should not be scrollabe. We are having a difficult time making it into a different screen sizes, since we are changing the margins and paddings for almost all different screen resolutions manually.

IS there a better way it can be achieved in CSS or jquery?

You can check the demo we have created at: http://demo.unboundcodes.com/khandelwal/

It is done for a few popular screen sizes, but we cannot still achieve success because there are still some spacing issues between header and main content on pages.

Comment: I've seen this achieved by removing all the content from the pages j/k

Answer (score 1):

The best solution to make your website responsive for different screen sizes and platforms is to use css media queries. You can specify the behavior for laptop screens, desktops, mobiles and tablets separately. In there you can use the following css property for laptops and desktops

```
overflow-x: hidden //if you want to stop x-axis scrolling
overflow-y: hidden //if you want to stop y-axis scrolling
overflow: hidden  //if you want to stop x and y-axis scrolling
```

For detailed description, please have a look into this:
[CSS Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Comment: `overflow` has an issue in iOS platform in different device.. for that issue search for iOS specific css for that device. Use `min-device-width` and `max-device-width` in that case. Many questions have already been asked about that issue.

Comment: Thank you for the help, since our design is a little different we converted it into a lot of <div> and applied the formula, but we are having problems in the other pages, where there is scroll in only the main content has a scroll, the concerned page is: http://demo.unboundcodes.com/khandelwal/services/audit-assurance-services/

So we are going to separately code for the main content page, but it was really insightful it made our framework stronger. 

Thank you @Code_Ninja for the extra tip on it, we will surely look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS property `overflow:hidden;` to the body to prevent scroll. Or you can secure the body dimensions with `width:100%; height:100%;`

Comment: Thank you, height 100% usually does not work with all the browsers, we have tried with overflow -x: hidden method, it is really workable like that.

Answer (score 0):

A quick, non-elegant but working standalone solution with inline CSS and no jQuery requirements. it works from IE9 too. try below code may be it helps

```
<body style="overflow:hidden; margin:0">
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div id="main" style="background-color:red">
            <div id="content">

            </div>
            <div id="footer">

            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script language="javascript">
        function autoResizeDiv()
        {
            document.getElementById('main').style.height = window.innerHeight +'px';
        }
        window.onresize = autoResizeDiv;
        autoResizeDiv();
    </script> </body>
```

Comment: Thank you, but our header and footer are designed separately so it creates a problem in overall structure!